# Lock Down Application

Tags: ios, security

Is it possible to lock down the device in iOS?

What I mean by lock down, is give complete control to the current running application and disabling multi-tasking etc. The reason for this is specifically for payment applications, basically to halt an attacker from being able to take over the process and be able to alter / read the memory, or seize the application.

Answer (score 4):

iOS devices are already locked down. Applications operate in their own sandbox and are unable to communicate with others.

Of course this may not apply to jailbroken handsets. You may wish to detect them a refuse to operate in that case. However people jailbreak their devices for many reasons and you may end up excluding honest, paying customers.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - I am aware of the sandbox environment, thanks - does this exclude the possibility of being able to gain access to global memory? Even a source would be great. I'm less concerned about high level attacks and more concerned with the low level ones.

Comment: iOS is a Unix variant and user applications do not run in a privileged account so there's no way to access global memory.

Comment: Note, though, that you can often read _files_ in other sandboxes (though the app would be rejected by Apple for doing so). So make sure you keep secure stuff in memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answers to your questions in [Apple documentation about iOS security](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/Security/_index.html)